# Cheese Error during camera setup: No device found

Tags: 18.04, webcam, cheese

When running Cheese in Ubuntu 18.04 the LED of the webcam is on, but Cheese does not work and provides the following output.

> (cheese:4175): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:05:59.527: Theme parsing error: cheese.css:7:35: The style property GtkScrollbar:min-slider-length is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version.
>   ** Message: 11:05:59.595: cheese-application.vala:211: Error during camera setup: No device found

`lsusb` provides the following output

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 0bda:b728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0930:6544 Toshiba Corp. TransMemory-Mini / Kingston DataTraveler 2.0 Stick (2GB) 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

ahh !! Right now I'm running cheese ... and it's already working.
but...

> (cheese:4900): Gtk-WARNING **: 08:44:04.184: Theme parsing error: gtk-main.css:73:38: Failed to import: Error al abrir el archivo /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.20/apps/gnome-builder.css: No existe el archivo o el directorio
>   (cheese:4900): Gtk-WARNING **: 08:44:04.244: Theme parsing error: cheese.css:7:35: The style property GtkScrollbar:min-slider-length is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version

This message worries me.

> (cheese:4900): cheese-WARNING **: 08:52:04.221: Se están desechando muchos búferes.: gstbasesink.c(2902): gst_base_sink_is_too_late (): /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstViewfinderBin:vf-bin/ClutterGstVideoSink:cluttergstvideosink0:
>   There may be a timestamping problem, or this computer is too slow.

I run `lsusb` and at the exit I do not see my webcam.

I'm so sorry I do not know what I'm doing wrong :(
Cheese already works normally.
but when starting ubuntu 18.04 LTS the webcam's LED does not turn off. To turn off the LED I have to start Cheese and then close it.

Comment: before it appeared now it does not appear when I run lsusb.
It is something strange. I have a webcam and my laptop

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1081387/edit) your question to provide supplementary information. Don't provide it in comments. Also, please use appropriate [markdown formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help).

Comment: Do you have a physical ON/OFF switch for webcam? Check function keys, for example <F10>.

Comment: the led of the webcam is on, but cheese does not work

Comment: Most people on this site don't speak Spanish, so please translate the error messages.